# Deploy a source install but cannot see the new CKAN instance - get Host not found?

Tags: ckan

I follow instructions to deploy a source install but get error when i try links http://www.default.ckanhosted.com
Host not found.
How i can check what's wrong with my deployement ?
http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/deployment.html#troubleshooting

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed this step:

> Replace default.ckanhosted.com and www.default.ckanhosted.com with the domain name for your site.

If you don't own a domain name, and you're local to the box, try `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` instead.